# How to loop over grouped Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, group-by

DataFrame:

```
  c_os_family_ss c_os_major_is l_customer_id_i
0      Windows 7                         90418
1      Windows 7                         90418
2      Windows 7                         90418
```

Code:

```py
for name, group in df.groupby('l_customer_id_i').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x)):
    print name
    print group
```

I'm trying to just loop over the aggregated data, but I get the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I wish to loop over every group. How do I do it?

Answer (score 396, accepted):

`df.groupby('l_customer_id_i').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))` does already return a dataframe, so you cannot loop over the groups anymore.

In general:

- `df.groupby(...)` returns a `GroupBy` object (a DataFrameGroupBy or SeriesGroupBy), and with this, you can iterate through the groups (as explained in the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups)). You can do something like:

  ```
  grouped = df.groupby('A')

  for name, group in grouped:
      ...
  ```
- When you apply a function on the groupby, in your example `df.groupby(...).agg(...)` (but this can also be `transform`, `apply`, `mean`, ...), you **combine** the result of **applying** the function to the different groups together in one dataframe (the apply and combine step of the 'split-apply-combine' paradigm of groupby). So the result of this will always be again a DataFrame (or a Series depending on the applied function).

Answer (score 137):

Here is an example of iterating over a `pd.DataFrame` grouped by the column `atable`. For this sample, "create" statements for an SQL database are generated within the `for` loop:

```py
import pandas as pd

def main():

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'atable':     ['Users', 'Users', 'Domains', 'Domains', 'Locks'],
        'column':     ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_a', 'col_b', 'col'],
        'column_type': ['varchar', 'varchar', 'int', 'varchar', 'varchar'],
        'is_null':    ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
    })

    print(df1)

    df1_grouped = df1.groupby('atable')

# iterate over each group
    for group_name, df_group in df1_grouped:
        print("\n-- Group with {} rows(s)".format(len(df_group)))
        print('CREATE TABLE {}('.format(group_name))


        x = 0
        for row_index, row in df_group.iterrows():
            x = x + 1
            col = row['column']
            column_type = row['column_type']
            is_null = 'NOT NULL' if row['is_null'] == 'No' else ''

            if x < len(df_group):
                print('\t{} {} {},'.format(col, column_type, is_null))
            else:
                print('\t{} {} {}'.format(col, column_type, is_null))

        print(");")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## output

```
    atable column column_type is_null
0    Users  col_1     varchar      No
1    Users  col_2     varchar      No
2  Domains  col_a         int     Yes
3  Domains  col_b     varchar      No
4    Locks    col     varchar     Yes

-- Group with 2 rows(s)
CREATE TABLE Domains(
    col_a int ,
    col_b varchar NOT NULL
);

-- Group with 1 rows(s)
CREATE TABLE Locks(
    col varchar
);

-- Group with 2 rows(s)
CREATE TABLE Users(
    col_1 varchar NOT NULL,
    col_2 varchar NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating that you can iterate through an individual `group` using `for row, data in group.iterrows()`!

Comment: Please make sure you read this related post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758

Answer (score 35):

You can iterate over the index values if your dataframe has already been created.

```
df = df.groupby('l_customer_id_i').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
for name in df.index:
    print name
    print df.loc[name]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Loop over groupby object

When you groupby a DataFrame/Series, you create a `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy` object which defines the `__iter__()` method, so can be iterated over like any other objects that define this method. It can be cast into a list/tuple/iterator etc. In each iteration, it returns a tuple whose first element is the grouper key and the second element is a dataframe created by the grouping; you can think of it like iteration over `dict_items` where in each iteration, the items are key-value tuples. Unless you select a column or columns on the groupby object, it returns all columns of the dataframe. The output of the following code illustrates this point.

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g1'],
    'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
})

grouped = df.groupby('A')

list(grouped)         # OK
dict(iter(grouped))   # OK

for x in grouped:
    print(f"    Type of x: {type(x).__name__}\n  Length of x: {len(x)}")
    print(f"Value of x[0]: {x[0]}\n Type of x[1]: {type(x[1]).__name__}")
    display(x[1])
```

[image: result1]

A pretty useful use case of a loop over groupby object is to split a dataframe into separate files. For example, the following creates two csv files (g_0.csv and g_1.csv) from a single dataframe.

```py
for i, (k, g) in enumerate(df.groupby('A')):
    g.to_csv(f"g_{i}.csv")
```

#### Loop over grouped dataframe

As mentioned above, groupby object splits a dataframe into dataframes by a key. So you can loop over each grouped dataframe like any other dataframe. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989939/19123103) for a comprehensive ways to iterate over a dataframe. The most performant way is probably `itertuples()`. Following is an example where a nested dictionary is created using a loop on the grouped dataframe:

```py
out = {}
for k, g in grouped:            # loop over groupby
    out[k] = {}
    for row in g.itertuples():  # loop over dataframe
        out[k][row.B] = row.C
print(out)
# {'g1': {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 4: 'd'}, 'g2': {3: 'c'}}
```