# Pandas: Iterate group by object

Tags: python, pandas

Given a data frame as following:

```
In [8]:
df
Out[8]:
Experiment  SampleVol   Mass
0   A   1   11
1   A   1   12
2   A   2   20
3   A   2   17
4   A   2   21
5   A   3   28
6   A   3   29
7   A   4   35
8   A   4   38
9   A   4   35
10  B   1   12
11  B   1   11
12  B   2   22
13  B   2   24
14  B   3   30
15  B   3   33
16  B   4   37
17  B   4   42
18  C   1   8
19  C   1   7
20  C   2   17
21  C   2   19
22  C   3   29
23  C   3   30
24  C   3   31
25  C   4   41
26  C   4   44
27  C   4   42
```

I would like to process some correlation study for the data frame of each Experiment. The study I want to conduct is to calculate the correlation of 'SampleVol' with its Mean('Mass').

The groupby function can help me to get the mean of masses.

`grp = df.groupby(['Experiment', 'SampleVol'])
grp.mean()`

```
Out[17]:
                       Mass
Experiment  SampleVol   
A            1         11.500000
             2         19.333333
             3         28.500000
             4         36.000000
B            1         11.500000
             2         23.000000
             3         31.500000
             4         39.500000
C            1          7.500000
             2         18.000000
             3         30.000000
             4         42.333333
```

I understand for each data frame I should use some numpy function to compute the correlation coefficient. But now, my question is how can I iterate the data frames for each Experiment.

Following is an example of the desired output.

```
Out[18]:

Experiment  Slope   Intercept
A            0.91   0.01
B            1.1    0.02
C            0.95   0.03
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: If iteration is your goal, you can simply do `for label, row in df.iterrows()`.

Comment: Can you post the desired output?

Comment: @JoeT.Boka I edit the post for the desired output.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin I would like to iterate the dataframes like {"SampleVol": [1, 2, 3, 4]; "Mass":[11.5, 19.33, 28.5, 36]}

Comment: Should post data as code object. People more likely to try to answer with runnable example. Note answer below, which I like, had to make up its own data, so does not directly answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to group on just the 'Experiment' column, rather than the two columns as you have above. You can iterate through the groups and perform a simple linear regression on the grouped values using the below code:

```
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

grp = df.groupby(['Experiment'])

output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Slope', 'Intercept'])

for name, group in grp:
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(group['SampleVol'], group['Mass'])
    output.loc[name] = [slope,intercept]
    
print(output)
```

[image]

For those curious, this is how I generated the dummy data and what it looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Experiment'] = np.array(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=12, freq='6h').strftime('%a'))
df['SampleVol'] = np.random.uniform(1,5,12)
df['Mass'] = np.random.uniform(10,42,12)
```

[image]

References:

- [How to loop over grouped Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405483/how-to-loop-over-grouped-pandas-dataframe)
- [scipy.stats.linregress — SciPy v1.0.0 Reference Guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html)
- [Group By: split-apply-combine — pandas 0.22.0 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups)