# Looping over groups in a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Consider this small example:

```
data={"X":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "Y":[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], "Z": [11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
frame=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["X","Y","Z"],index=["A","A","A","B","B"])
```

I want to group `frame` with

```
grouped=frame.groupby(frame.index)
```

Then I want to loop over the groups by:

```
for group in grouped:
```

But I'm stuck on the next step: How can I extract the `group` in each loop as a pandas DataFrame so I can further process it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop over grouped Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405483/how-to-loop-over-grouped-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: That is quite similar, but not exactly the same problem. Here, I missed the name-part of the for-command. The other problem is about difference between loop up over or directly use a summary function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`df.groupby` returns an iterable of 2-tuples: the index, and the group. You can iterate over each group like this:

```
for _, g in frame.groupby(frame.index):
    .... # do something with `g`
```

However, if you want to perform some operation on the groups, there are probably better ways than iteration.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I missed the issue, that i get a tuple, so this way it works. thanks.

Comment: @coldspeed , how can I iterate through individual group elements in your solution?

Comment: @TonyMathew inside the loop you can access variable g.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example:

```
groups = frame.groupby(level=0)

for n,g in groups:
    print('This is group '+ str(n)+'.')
    print(g)
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```
This is group A.
   X  Y   Z
A  1  6  11
A  2  7  12
A  3  8  13


This is group B.
   X   Y   Z
B  4   9  14
B  5  10  15
```