# Drag down formula in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to  calculate the (multiplier x value) for the 5 years after a True, for each fruit? Shown the formulae here for clarity

```
df   

fruit   year     value     Criteria        multiplier        multiplier x value
apple   1950      2
apple   1951      3
apple   1952      3
apple   1953      4
apple   1954      5
apple   1955      4       True           1.4                        (=1.4*4)
apple   1956      7                                                 (=1.4*7)
..
apple   2000      8                                                 (=1.4*8)

banana  1950     333                                                
banana  1951     335
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df[df['Criteria'] == True].index` to find the indices of all `True` rows.
Now you can fill the subsequent rows with the corresponding multiplier like this:

```
for i in df[df['Criteria'] == True].index:
  df.loc[i:i+4, 'multiplier'] = df.loc[i]['multiplier']
```

and finally write the results to the `multiplier x value` column like this:

```
df['multiplier x value'] = df['multiplier'] * df['value']
```

This assumes that all your emtpy multiplier cells are filled with `None` or `0`.

If you need this for each fruit, use `groupby` to split the DataFrame and run the loop on each subframe:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for subframe in [x for _, x in df.groupby('fruit')]:
  for i in subframe[subframe['Criteria'] == True].index:
    subframe.loc[i:i+4, 'multiplier'] = subframe.loc[i]['multiplier']
  result = pd.concat([result, subframe])

result['multiplier x value'] = result['multiplier'] * result['value']
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining what ```for subframe in [x for _, x in df.groupby('fruit')``` means? I understand the groupby but not the bit before.

Comment: @asd: `groupby` returns a tuple of the group name and the group data, so what happens is that the names are assigned to `_` (i.e. are not needed and will be discarded) and the data are assigned to `x` and used as a list, which is iterated through by the outer `for` loop. You can `print(subframe)` to see the content.

Comment: Further reading on [iterating through groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups).

Comment: See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797633/looping-over-groups-in-a-grouped-dataframe).