# How to interrogate a python object about its structure?

Tags: python, oop, object

Is there a way to programmatically determine an object's structure/model, it's constituent parts, how it can be iterated and manipulated and transformed, broken down and built back up?

Trial and error are great teachers. I take their classes every day. But here I'm looking for a way to "work smarter" or at least differently.

A little background: I recently spent way too many hours incorrectly handling a pandas `groupby` object because I did not understand the building block parts and types that it is made of. I did not correctly handle the tuple that is returned when iterating on a `groupby` object. I now have a slightly better, but not at all sufficient, understanding of this particular object: e.g., a `groupby` obj breaks down into "`params`" and "`table`" when iterated. `table`, in turn, is made up of `index` and `rows`. But I'm still not sure how to handle `rows`: what they're made of or break down into. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54713287/9677043) includes code to reproduce the issue: see Edit 2 at the bottom of original post.

But this is a particular case; my question is more general. My question is, if I don't already know the structure or "model" of a python object/type, how can I query the object to reveal this information textually or, even better perhaps, graphically?

---

**Edit**:

For purposes of exploration and learning, below I try to run every `str` method on a `str` object via a `for` loop. The `meth` obj is interpreted correctly in the first two lines of the loop (e.g., `__add__` and `__class__`), but is interpreted as `meth` when I try to run `obj.meth`. How can I fix this?

Input:

```
obj = 'my_string'

object_methods = [method_name for method_name in dir(obj)
                  if callable(getattr(obj, method_name))]

print(len(object_methods))
print(object_methods)
```

Output:

```
77
['__add__', '__class__', . . ., 'upper', 'zfill']
```

Input:

```
for meth in object_methods:
    print(meth)
    try:
        print('obj.meth for obj', obj, 'and method', meth, ':') 
        obj.meth
    except AttributeError as e:
        print('obj.meth for obj', obj, 'and method', meth, ': AttributeError:', e)
```

Output:

```
__add__
obj.meth for obj my_string and method __add__ :
obj.meth for obj my_string and method __add__ : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'meth'
__class__
obj.meth for obj my_string and method __class__ :
obj.meth for obj my_string and method __class__ : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'meth'
. . .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[__dict___](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)**  and **[dir](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/dir)** in order to see object model.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

jack = Person('jack',23)
print(jack.__dict__)
print(dir(jack))
```

Output:

```
{'age': 23, 'name': 'jack'}
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'age', 'name']
```

Comment: `dir(obj)` gives me a list of attributes/methods, I've used that before. I tried `obj = 'string'`; `obj.__dict__` and got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__dict__'`.  In what contexts or for what types of objects does it work?

Comment: From the docs: object.__dict__
A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes.See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reflection-in-python/ for more

Comment: I read the geeks post and am testing some code but getting errors which I added to my original post. Can you help me figure out how to fix this code?