# How can I create a macro to loop through all columns in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm analyzing a data set with information from soccer players. I have the soccer player name, his club and all skills. I want to get the mean value of all players from a club and check the skill in which the club is better. For instance, what club has the faster players, the tallest players, etc.

This is what my data looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Club": ["Palmeiras", "SPFC", "Corinthians", "Palmeiras", "SPFC"],
        "Player": ["FFFFF", "EEEE", "DDDD", "CCCC", "BBBB"],
        "Balance": [70, 80, 90, 50, 60],
        "Speed": [90, 89, 70, 88, 80],
        "Aggression": [70, 74, 80, 85, 66],
    }
)
```

In this example, I get the club with the highest average speed:

```
print("Club with highest speed: " + df.groupby("Club")["Speed"].mean().reset_index().sort_values("Speed", ascending=False).iloc[0, 0])
```

I want to print the same thing for all skills, the club with highest speed, the club with the highest balance and so on. I thought I could use something similar to what I did other times with `df.iterrows()`, however, I'm having a hard time combining this with the `groupby` function.

I've also found this example [How to loop over grouped Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405483/how-to-loop-over-grouped-pandas-dataframe), but it didn't work for me.

Comment: The problem is that I will have to write all variables and it's a big dataset. The example I gave was a small one, but the intention is to replicate in a much bigger...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a combination of `groupby().mean()` to get all the mean stats by clubs and `idxmax()` to identify the clubs with maximum mean:

```
df.groupby('Club').mean().idxmax()
```

Output:

```
Balance       Corinthians
Speed           Palmeiras
Aggression    Corinthians
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Quang Hoang already solved your problem, but if you want to get everything in a single dataframe, you could do as below.

```
means = df.groupby('Club').mean().max()
best = df.groupby('Club').mean().idxmax()
res = pd.DataFrame([means, best], index=['Mean', 'Team']).T

In [1]: print(res)
Out[1]: 
            Mean    Team
Balance     90      Corinthians
Speed       89      Palmeiras
Aggression  80      Corinthians
```