# How to set rolling window size by size of each group?

Tags: python, window, grouping, rolling-computation

I have a data frame like below:

```
>df

ID    Value
---------------
1       1.0
1       2.0
1       3.0
1       4.0
2       6.0
2       7.0
2       8.0
3       2.0
```

I want to calculate `min/max/sum/mean/var` on 'value' field of last `int(group size /2)` records of each group instead of fix number of records.

- For ID =1, apply `min/max/sum/mean/var` on 'value' field of last 4/2=2 records
- For ID =2, apply `min/max/sum/mean/var` on 'value' field of last 3/2=1 records.
- For ID =3, apply `min/max/sum/mean/var` on 'value' field of last 1 records since it only have one records in the group.

so the output should be

```
             Value
ID    min   max  sum  mean  var
----------------------------------
1     3.0   4.0  7.0  3.5    0.5 # the last 4/2 rows for group with ID =1
2     7.0   7.0  7.0  7.0    0.5 # the last 3/2 rows for group with ID =2
3     2.0   2.0  2.0  2.0    Nan # the last 1 rows for group with ID =3
```

I am thinking to use the `rolling` function like below:

```
df_group=df.groupby('ID')
           .apply(lambda x: x \
                           .sort_values(by=['ID'])
                           .rolling(window=int(x.size/2),min_periods=1)
                           .agg({'Value':['min','max','sum','mean','var']})
                           .tail(1)
                  )
```

but the result turns out to be as below

```
                Value
        min max sum    mean  var
ID                      
------------------------------------------------
1   3   1.0 4.0 10.0    2.5 1.666667
2   6   6.0 8.0 21.0    7.0 1.000000
3   7   2.0 2.0 2.0     2.0 NaN
```

it seems the x.size does not work at all.

Is there any way to set the rolling size based on group size?

Comment: Hi, can you share what you've tried to do as well as an expected result (dataframe or other) ?

Comment: I've updated the question with what I 've done and expected output, any hint?

Comment: Don't know why you need to roll over the dataframe, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223067/3941704 for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, with :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ID=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3],
                      Value=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,2]))

print(df)
##
   ID  Value
0   1      1
1   1      2
2   1      3
3   1      4
4   2      6
5   2      7
6   2      8
7   3      2
```

Loop over groups as below

```
#Object to store the result
stats = []

#Group over ID
for ID, Values in df.groupby('ID'):
    # tail : to get last n values, with n max between 1 and group length / 2
    # describe : to get the statistics
    _stat = Values.tail(max(1,int(len(Values)/2)))['Value'].describe()
    #Add group ID to the result
    _stat.loc['ID'] = ID
    #Store the result
    stats.append(_stat)

#Create the new dataframe
pd.DataFrame(stats).set_index('ID')
```

Result

```
     count  mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max
ID                                                   
1.0    2.0   3.5  0.707107  3.0  3.25  3.5  3.75  4.0
2.0    1.0   8.0       NaN  8.0  8.00  8.0  8.00  8.0
3.0    1.0   2.0       NaN  2.0  2.00  2.0  2.00  2.0
```

---

Links :

- [How to loop over grouped Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405483/how-to-loop-over-grouped-pandas-dataframe)
- [Series Describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.describe.html)