# Doing multithread on pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I have a pandas dataframe consist of 1 million of rows. this data consist of transaction history of customers, hence, 1 customer might have multiple rows. For each customer, I have a function to run, so I need to use apply lambda function using groupby customer ID.
But how do I speed up the process with multithreading? my machine has 8 CPU cores, and I wish to use all of them, currently I am only able to use 1 core.
Let's say in those 1 million of rows, and I have total 100k unique customers, I wish to execute 12.5k customers for each CPU core, it would make the process 8 times faster!

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you looked at dask? You won't get near as 8x speedup though due to processing overheads. What function are you running on every row?

Comment: Also mpi4py....

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module from python. It is a wrapper for the threading and multiprocessing libraries with (in my opinion) a simple interface. I would propose to not use multiple threads but multiple processes for a speed-up.

After aggregating the customers by ID, you can pass the customer data to a function which is the target of a new process. You can do this using `submit(<args>)` on an executor object, which returns a future object and starts a new process. When calling `.result()` on the future object, the current process will wait until the function in the new process has returned and return the result.

**Example:**

```
import concurrent.futures

def fancy_function(data):
  # Do something
  return 42 

processes = []
# let DF be the dataframe
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
  for name, group in DF.groupby('customerId'):
    processes.append(executor.submit(fancy_function, group))
results = []
for process in processes:
  results.append(process.result())
```

Some sources:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html
- https://medium.com/contentsquare-engineering-blog/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-ece023ad55a
- [How to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)
- [How to loop over grouped Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405483/how-to-loop-over-grouped-pandas-dataframe)