# Deprecation Warning with groupby.apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python script that reads in data from a csv file

The code runs fine, but everytime it runs I get this Deprecation message:

```
DeprecationWarning: DataFrameGroupBy.apply operated on the grouping columns. This behavior is deprecated, and in a future version of pandas the grouping columns will be excluded from the operation. Either pass `include_groups=False` to exclude the groupings or explicitly select the grouping columns after groupby to silence this warning.
```

the warning stems from this piece of code:

```
fprice = df.groupby(['StartDate', 'Commodity', 'DealType']).apply(lambda group: -(group['MTMValue'].sum() - (group['FixedPriceStrike'] * group['Quantity']).sum()) / group['Quantity'].sum()).reset_index(name='FloatPrice')
```

to my understanding, I am performing the apply function on my groupings,but then I am disregarding the groupings and not using them anymore to be apart of my dataframe. I am confused about the directions to silence the warning

here is some sample data that this code uses:

```
TradeID  TradeDate  Commodity  StartDate   ExpiryDate FixedPrice Quantity MTMValue
-------- ---------- ---------  ---------   ---------- ---------- -------- ---------
 aaa   01/01/2024   (com1,com2) 01/01/2024  01/01/2024    10        10      100.00 
 bbb   01/01/2024   (com1,com2) 01/01/2024  01/01/2024    10        10      100.00 
 ccc   01/01/2024   (com1,com2) 01/01/2024  01/01/2024    10        10      100.00
```

and here is the expected output from this data:

```
TradeID  TradeDate  Commodity  StartDate   ExpiryDate FixedPrice Quantity MTMValue  FloatPrice
-------- ---------- ---------  ---------   ---------- ---------- -------- --------- ----------
 aaa   01/01/2024   (com1,com2) 01/01/2024  01/01/2024    10        10      100.00      0
 bbb   01/01/2024   (com1,com2) 01/01/2024  01/01/2024    10        10      100.00      0
 ccc   01/01/2024   (com1,com2) 01/01/2024  01/01/2024    10        10      100.00      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### About `include_groups` parameter

The `include_groups` parameter of [DataFrameGroupBy.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.2/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) is new in pandas version 2.2.0. It is basically a transition period (2.2.0 -> 3.0) parameter added to help communicating a changing behavior (with warnings) and to tackle [pandas Issue 7155](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7155). In most cases you should be able to just set it to `False` to silent the warning (see below).

#### Setup

Let's say you have a pandas DataFrame `df` and a dummy function `myfunc` for apply, and you want to

- Group by column `'c'`
- Apply `myfunc` on each group

```py
>>> df
      a  value     c
0   foo     10  cat1
1   bar     20  cat2
2   baz     30  cat1
3  quux     40  cat2


>>> def myfunc(x):
    print(x, '\n')
```

#### include_groups = True (Old behavior)

- This is the default *behavior* in pandas <2.2.0 (there is no `include_groups` parameter)
- pandas 2.2.0 and above (likely until 3.0) will still default to this but issue a DeprecationWarning.
- The grouping column(s), here `'c'` is included in the `DataFrameGroupBy`

```
>>> df.groupby('c').apply(myfunc)
     a  value     c
0  foo     10  cat1
2  baz     30  cat1 

      a  value     c
1   bar     20  cat2
3  quux     40  cat2
```

Now as mentioned in [Issue 7155](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7155), keeping the grouping column `c` in the dataframe passed to `apply` is unwanted behavior. Most people will not expect `c` to be present here. The [answer of bue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78030503/3015186) has actually an example how this could lead to bugs; apply on `np.mean` and expect there be less columns (causes a bug if your grouping column is numerical).

#### include_groups = False (new behavior)

- This will remove the warning in the pandas > 2.2.0 (<3.0)
- This will be the default in future version of pandas (likely 3.0)
- This is what you likely would want to have; drop the grouping column `'c'`:

```py
>>> df.groupby('c').apply(myfunc, include_groups=False)
     a  value
0  foo     10
2  baz     30 

      a  value
1   bar     20
3  quux     40
```

---

#### Details just for this use case

Your grouping columns are

```
['StartDate', 'Commodity', 'DealType']
```

In the apply function you use the following columns:

```
['MTMValue',  'FixedPriceStrike', 'Quantity']
```

i.e., you do not need any of the *grouping columns* in your *apply*, and therefore you can use `include_groups=False` which also removes the warning.

```py
fprice = df.groupby(['StartDate', 'Commodity', 'DealType']).apply(lambda group: -(group['MTMValue'].sum() - (group['FixedPriceStrike'] * group['Quantity']).sum()) / group['Quantity'].sum(), include_groups=False).reset_index(name='FloatPrice')
```

Comment: This is such a useful explanation. I wanted to retain the column AND avoid Deprecation warning, so after understanding what I'm getting into, I just created a copy of the column and just grouped on the copy; so I retained my original column!

Comment: what if you do need the grouping column? will future pandas still support it, even though it issues 'warning'?

Comment: Looking at the discussion in [pandas #7155](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7155) I get the feeling that it will be unsupported. I guess I would then just use groupby as iterator like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27422749/3015186). Not sure if there will other better ways to do it in pandas 3.x.

Answer (score 7):

I made a very simple data frame, to understand what goes on.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,2,2,2],[1,2,3,4,5,6]], index=['a','b']).T
```

```py
In []: print(df)
Out[]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  2  4
4  2  5
5  2  6
```

we will now group by column a.

have a look at the difference output with `include_groups=True` (the corrent default - pandas version 2.2.0) and `include_groups=False` which will be the only way allowed in the future.

```py
In []: df.groupby('a').apply(np.mean, include_groups=True)
Out[]: 
a
1    1.5
2    3.5
dtype: float64
```

- (1+1+1+1+2+3) / 6 = 1.5
- (2+2+2+4+5+6) / 6 = 3.5

```py
In []: df.groupby('a').apply(np.mean, include_groups=False)
Out[]: 
a
1    2.0
2    5.0
dtype: float64
```

- (1+2+3) / 3 = 2.0
- (4+5+6) / 3 = 5.0

For me, this made things pretty clear.
What the right thing is for your case, include_groups True or False, I don't know.

Comment: Your example makes sense but after understanding the explanation below